# Force to open social apps by redirecting page in c# in smart phone and tablet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook, webforms

This is the scenario :  The user will go to mydomain.com with a smart phone or tablet

and mydomain.com will be redirected to facebook.com/mypage

It works but doesnt fire the Facebook app. I want Facebook app opens when user goes to my site.

If the user directly goes to facebook.com/mypage, It opens Facebook App. But why not with my redirection...

I have tried...

```
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.facebook.com/mypage");
        Response.End();
```

and

```
         Response.BufferOutput = true;
         Response.Redirect("http://www.facebook.com/mypage");
```

But none of the works. What can be the trick here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the Facebook URL schema to open the app. See this previous post for an example: [Facebook URL schemes on a mobile website, open app if its installed, otherwise go to the webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275174/facebook-url-schemes-on-a-mobile-website-open-app-if-its-installed-otherwise-g)

Essentially, the device recognizes that URIs on the "fb" protocol should open in the app.

Comment: Allright Ben, thats a nice point. But my problem is that I need to got that spesific URI with c# .net redirecting from the browser. Thats the problem. When I redirect, It opens the link in the browser again :(