# How to open the native Facebook app from a react app link?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my react web app I have a link to share a website url on Facebook:

```
<Link href={`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${this.props.shareUrl}`}>
```

Share on Facebook

I could also use a plain html link like so

```
<a href={`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${this.props.shareUrl}`}>Share on Facebook</a>
```

When this is clicked Safari is launched and the Facebook web page is displayed.

What would I need to do to get the native Facebook ios or android app to launch (instead of a browser) if it is installed? Could I carry on using this link or would I need to use a share button or install the Fb SDK?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275174/facebook-url-schemes-on-a-mobile-website-open-app-if-its-installed-otherwise-g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook URL schemes on a mobile website, open app if its installed, otherwise go to the webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275174/facebook-url-schemes-on-a-mobile-website-open-app-if-its-installed-otherwise-g)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to open a **Facebook** app from **URL**. It works for me.

```
 Linking.openURL("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/FixadorPT/");
```